# Random task deadlocks/memory corruption in wpf application in virtual machine running .net 4.8

Tags: wpf, task, task-parallel-library, mahapps.metro

So I have spent the better part of two days troubleshooting a very weird issue. At no point running my application on the development workstation or a physical workstation did I ever encounter any issues running the application.

The app has reached a point in the development lifecycle were it was time to start doing more targeted regression testing. This included running the application within virtual machines as I wanted to support the application running in virtualized environments.

Well upon testing in virtualized environments I noticed a very weird issue randomly any command I had binded that opened a child window would sometimes not work. The child window will not render and the button would be greyed out due to the canexcute of the command giving false since it thought the command was still running. This issue cannot be reproduced on a physical machine and have tried greatly.

After research I saw a lot about virtual machines and wpf rendering and people stating to force software rendering instead of allowing hardware rendering. This did not work either.

Further research/testing found this didn't have to be a task that rendered a simple child window and it could be any task that would lead to this random issue.

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head I have found these articles

https://www.gresearch.co.uk/2019/12/20/deep-dives-in-debugging-when-it-really-isnt-your-fault/

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26990

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/10065

Long story short is that this is an issue with .net 4.8 and if I run in a virtual machine running 4.7.2 these issues are not reproducible. I am going to leave this open though as I did notice something odd after discovering this information and testing further.

I have discovered that if I run application on a virtual machine with .net 4.7.2 with TWO or more vCPUs that these random issues are not reproducible. But if I run on a virtual machine with .net 4.7.2 and ONE vCPU the issue still arises. Furthermore if I run application on .net 4.8 with TWO or more vCPUs the issue arises. Lastly if I run on .net 4.8 with ONE vCPU the issue is not reproducible.